# How to send nested json object to server using spring mvc + jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-boot

I have `Hotel` entity and it has another object called `Location`.

```
@Entity
public class Hotel implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;
      String name;
      @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="LOC_ID")
      Location location;
      //GETTER SETTER
  }
```

`Location` object like that:

```
@Entity
public class Location implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="LOC_ID")
    private Long id;

    String name;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Location(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I can send Location object to server (`{"name":"MyNewLoc"}`).
I can send Hotel object to server with only name it's also ok (`{"name":"NewHotel"}`).

But when I try to send hotel object with name and Location attribute (`{"name":"New Hotel","location":{"name":"MyNewLoc"}}`), I get 400 POST error and this response;

```
exception:"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException"

message:"Could not read JSON: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: org.maskapsiz.sosyalkovan.domain.Hotel["location"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: org.maskapsiz.sosyalkovan.domain.Hotel["location"])"
```

I am using jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13 and Spring boot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to POST nested entities with Spring Data REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569399/how-to-post-nested-entities-with-spring-data-rest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added @RestResource(exported = false) and it works for me.

```
@Entity
@RestResource(exported = false)
public class Location implements Serializable {
}
```