# Spring Rest Service - Template must not be null or empty

Tags: spring, rest

I get this error and I dont know why, this rest Service worked for a long time but now it does not.
Does anyone know why? Thanks

```
"timestamp":1460259139272,"status":"400","error":"Could not read JSON:         Template must not be null or
 empty! (through reference chain:         com.smartinnotec.aposoft.dao.domain.InstitutionUserConnection[\"user
\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:     Template must not    be     null
  or empty! (through reference chain:
```

This is my request:

[image]

and this is the class:

```
@Document(collection = "InstitutionUserConnection")
public class InstitutionUserConnection implements Comparable<InstitutionUserConnection> {

@JsonView(RestServiceResponseView.InstitutionUserConnectionPublic.class)
@Id
private String id;
@JsonView(RestServiceResponseView.InstitutionUserConnectionPublic.class)
@DBRef
private User user;
@DBRef
@JsonView(RestServiceResponseView.InstitutionUserConnectionPublic.class)
private Institution institution;
@DBRef
@JsonView(RestServiceResponseView.InstitutionUserConnectionPublic.class)
private Institution differentName;
@DBRef
@JsonView(RestServiceResponseView.InstitutionUserConnectionPublic.class)
private InstitutionDummyTest institutionDummyTest;
```

It is really crazy, I have copied all properties an methods from Institution class to InstitutionDummyTest class, so this classes are the same, if I set institution in rest request than it does not work, with institutionDummyTest it works. I actually have no idea whats going on here? I would be thanksful for all helps.

[EDIT]
Its really hard, I have no idea whats going wrong, I switched for a few commits from Windows to Ubuntu and than back to Windows. Maybe this is a problem with the enlcoding? Does anyone have an ideo concerning encoding

[SOLVED]
Simple solution: 
spring-boot-starter-data-rest was in deh classpath.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569399/how-to-post-nested-entities-with-spring-data-rest

Comment: I read this but I do not have any URLs in my JSON request.