# How do I post nested entity to Spring Data Rest without setting @RestResource(exported = false)?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26384796/1706691) as a solution to POSTing an entity with nested entities. But I want to  make a RESTful POST request.

That is, I want nested entities to be represented with links.

As an example, suppose my client wants to POST a student:

```
class Student {
  String name;
  Address address;
}

RepresentationModel<Address> address = //feign call to get previously saved address from Spring Data Rest endpoint
Student student = new Student();
student.setName("name");
student.setAddress(address.getContent());
client.save(student); //feign call to save student
```

This last call fails because Spring Data Rest expects `address` to be represented as a URI instead of a nested object. How can I add the URI?

I've tried making the `Student` `address` field be of type `RepresentationModel<Address>` but this doesn't work. The server throws an error saying addressId can't be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have your Student:

```java
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

and Address:

```java
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String houseNumber;
    private String zipCode;
    ...
}
```

And because of the fact that Student has a relation to Address you either have to make the relation not required and you wouldn't need the Address in your POST request. Or it's required that the address is already persisted before you try to create the Student and therefore you need the Address in your POST call.

---

So the flow would look like this:

- Create the address with post -> Get the Id/URI back
- With the Id/URI create the Student.

And to implement this you have to adjust the object in the client to the required one. So create a Stundent that looks similar to the required json like this:

```java
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private URI addressReference //probably need to rename this or use JsonProperty annotation
}
```

Comment: This works. But I don't understand why the URI would be here. Valid HAL would have this under _links or within _embedded. I have another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957622/can-spring-data-rest-use-links-per-hal-spec) to ask that question.

Comment: Alright Imma take a look at this too. Didn't work that much with Data Rest :/

Comment: But If I was able to help I'd really appreciate when you accept this answer :D

Comment: And I read your other question I have a general answer but I'm not happy with this. I'm trying to recreate this post scenario with data rest also for this question here, but it's doing some very weird magic/stuff rn :/ I hope I'll be able to figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks for your help here and for looking at my other question.