# Can Spring Data Rest use _links per HAL spec?

Tags: rest, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

A POST request with media type, "application/hal+json", is issued to a Spring Data Rest endpoint, `/api/groupMembers`. It contains the following payload:

```
{
  "id":null,
  "_links":{
    "group":{"href":"http://local:8080/api/groups/7"},
    "item":{"href":"http://local:8080/api/items/10689"},
    "groupItem":{"href":"http://local:8080/api/items/10689"}
  }
}
```

This is similar to the example provided in the [HAL specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal#section-3). All of these URIs point to existing resources and can be dereferenced in a web browser.

However, these Link Objects do not appear to be assembled correctly by Spring Data Rest on the server:

```
TRACE 20248 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation@15aacfd5, Resource { content: GroupMember(id=null, group=null, item=null, groupItem=null), links: [] }, org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler@1d8f0f1a, application/hal+json]
```

Why doesn't Spring Data Rest populate these properties (`group`, `item`, `groupItem`) using the Link Objects?

**Update**

A GET request to `/api/GroupMembers/1` produces:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "_links":{
    "group":{"href":"http://local:8080/api/groups/1"},
    "item":{"href":"http://local:8080/api/items/689"},
    "groupItem":{"href":"http://local:8080/api/items/689"}
  }
}
```

So, Spring Data Rest can produce/serialize this JSON HAL response but cannot handle (deserialize) the same JSON HAL in a request.

**Update 2**

The GroupMember entity is:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class GroupMember {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="groupId")
    private Group group;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="itemId")
    private Item item;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="groupItemId")
    private Item groupItem;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

POST /api/groupMembers

```java
{
  "id":null,
  "group": "http://local:8080/api/groups/7",
  "item": "http://local:8080/api/items/10689",
  "groupItem": "http://local:8080/api/items/10689"
}
```

_links are just metadata

Comment: Thanks. I know that POSTing the JSON in your answer works. However, as far as I know, this doesn't meet the HAL spec. What I'd like to know is if there is a way to POST to a Spring Data REST endpoint with JSON conforming to the HAL spec.

Comment: Actually this is a valid HAL document. Remember that _links are optional. Also nowhere in the spec says how this issue should be addressed. Here is a good discussion around this issue: https://evertpot.com/working-with-hal-in-put/

What you are trying to achieve is completely valid but I think you will have to use spring-hateoas directly since it is not the approach used by the data rest module

Comment: Thanks for the link. I agree that the JSON in your answer is valid HAL. However, it seems asymmetrical that the Spring Data REST GET response includes `_links` to show relationships while they get ignored on a POST request. If I read it correctly, the author of your article seems to take the approach of using `_links` in a POST request so that it is symmetric with GET responses. It's unfortunate that Spring Data REST doesn't take this approach.